# Using libraries with LimeJS HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, limejs

I was wondering if I could use any libraries I want like  Node.JS, JQuery with LimeJS ? it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use jQuery with it, though I have not tested.  Make use of jQuery's [***noConflict function***](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Use it something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: and with socket.IO any idea ?